# Autocomplete while searching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I want to implement the autocomplete feature while searching, I tried to it in many ways but wasn't able to, I wanted to put like we google search. Currently when we type the whole word then only the suggestion dropdown is coming up.
What exaclty i want is like lets say the user is searching 'Developer' and the moment the user types 'de' all the words related to 'de' should come up.
Can someone help me out.

```
// CourseSearch.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import "./calendarheader.css";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import logo from "../assets/logo-pwc-white-2x.png";
import GlobalContext from "../context/GlobalContext";
import RegistrationForm from "./registration";
import ModalContainer from "./Modalcontainer";
import "./eventmodal.css";
import "./modalcontainer.css";
import CourseDetailsModal from "./CourseDetailsModal";

const CourseSearch = () => {
  const { monthIndex, setMonthIndex } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCourseDetails, setSelectedCourseDetails] = useState(null);
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.trim() === "") {
      setSearchResults([]);
      return;
    }

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // setLoading(true);
      fetch(`http://localhost:4000/course-details/${searchTerm}`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Data received:", data);
          setSearchResults(data);
          setDropdownOpen(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        });
    }, 300);
    setTypingTimeout(timeout);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const handleReset = () => {
    setMonthIndex(
      monthIndex === dayjs().month()
        ? monthIndex + Math.random()
        : dayjs().month()
    );
    closeDropdown();
  };


  const closeDropdown = () => {
    setSearchTerm("");
    setSearchResults([]);
    setDropdownOpen(false);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setSelectedCourseDetails(null);
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="header-row-2">
        <button onClick={handleReset} className="button-calendar-today">
          Today
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={handlePrevMonth}
          className="button-navigation-arrows"
        >
          <span className="material-icons-outlined cursor-pointer text-orange-50 mx-2">
            chevron_left
          </span>
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={handleNextMonth}
          className="button-navigation-arrows"
        >
          <span className="material-icons-outlined cursor-pointer text-orange-50 mx-2">
            chevron_right
          </span>
        </button>
        <p className="ml-4 text-xl text-black-500">
          {dayjs(new Date(dayjs().year(), monthIndex)).format("MMMM YYYY")}
        </p>
        <div className="searchbar">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="Search any course"
            className="input"
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
          />
          {searchResults.length > 0 && dropdownOpen && (
            <div className="dropdown">
              <ul>
                {searchResults.map((result) => (
                  <li
                    key={result.id}
                    onClick={() => handleCourseClick(result)}
                  >
                    <strong>{result.courseName}</strong>
                    <br />
                    Start Date: {result.startProgramDates} End Date:
                    {result.endProgramDates}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {selectedCourseDetails && isModalOpen && (
          <CourseDetailsModal
            courseDetails={selectedCourseDetails}
            onClose={closeModal}
            onApplyClick={() => {
              closeModal(); // Close modal after clicking "Apply"
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default CourseSearch;
```

This it he API data I am fetching

```
0:{id: 59, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '15-01-2024', endProgramDates: '19-01-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}

1:{id: 60, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '22-01-2024', endProgramDates: '25-01-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}

2:{id: 67, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '05-02-2024', endProgramDates: '09-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}

3:{id: 68, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '12-02-2024', endProgramDates: '16-02-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}

4:{id: 79, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '04-03-2024', endProgramDates: '08-03-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}

5:{id: 80, source: 'Cloud Academy', startProgramDates: '18-03-2024', endProgramDates: '22-03-2024', startTime: '8:00 AM ET', …}
```

Comment: There is AutoComplete component in Material-UI. You can use this component. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/

Comment: I tried to do the same, but it was complicated for me to integrate that with this existing code. 
So thinking if anyone from here could help me out.